# returning controller not found when using it as "controller@method" in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make the resource route of steps work with id passed in the link like this "/steps/{howitwork:id}/create" and the create method looks like this:

```
public function create(HowItWork $how){
  ...
}
```

so before I define the resource route in the controller:

```
Route::get('steps/{howitwork:id}/create/', [
   'as' => 'steps.create',
   'uses' => 'StepController@create'
]);
```

what the app returning is:

> Target class [StepController] does not exist.

Comment: `HowItWorkController` doesn't show up in the code you posted, are you sure you posted the correct lines?

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote the wrong error, can you check it now?

Comment: Have you tried using `'\App\Http\Controllers\StepController@create'`?

Comment: ok thank you, @sinan just solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have add code under the resource route and try with this.

```
**Route::resrouce('something', SomethingController::class);
**Route::get('steps/{howitwork}/create', [StepController::class, 'create'])->as('steps.create');
```

Comment: I used `name` in place of `as`, overall it works!
thanks

Comment: Ah yess i forgot to put name.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use this syntax:

```
Route::get('/', [YourController::class, 'your-method'])->name('your-route-name')->middleware(['your-middleware-1', 'your-middleware-2', 'your-middleware-3']);
```

Comment: that isn't what I mean